# Weblogic refuses to start for different user

Tags: weblogic, weblogic9.x

I have a Weblogic instance that starts fine for one user, but when a different user tries to start the same code it fails like this:

```
<Jun 26, 2010 8:19:30 AM EDT> <Info> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000377> <Starting WebLogic Server with Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM Version 1.5.0_15-b04 from Sun Microsystems Inc.> 
<Jun 26, 2010 8:19:32 AM EDT> <Info> <Management> <BEA-141107> <Version: WebLogic Server 9.2 MP3  Mon Mar 10 08:28:41 EDT 2008 1096261 > 
<Jun 26, 2010 8:19:36 AM EDT> <Critical> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000362> <Server failed. Reason: [Management:141266]Parsing Failure in config.xml: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1> 
<Jun 26, 2010 8:19:36 AM EDT> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000365> <Server state changed to FAILED>
```

I have checked the config.xml file and it looks fine.  Has anyone seen this?  The lack of info in the error message is very frustrating, as well as the fact that it works fine with a different user.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, it turned out to be a bad path.  Somehow one user was able to follow a symbolic link but the other user was not.  Still not sure why but changing the path to avoid the symbolic link did the trick.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Weblogic has specific roles with varying privileges. Is it possible User A is part of `Administrators` or `Operators` groups - while User B is not?

See the list of roles here:

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs91/secwlres/secroles.html#1221588